# Shared scripts in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. I calculated some equations on Matlab and save it .mat file. And closed the whole project. In this .mat file there are only constants. But I should save this file in the script so as .m file. My teacher wants to see my codes, scripts.

How can I reach my scripts of this file? Or Do I need to create my project with the script?

Comment: You wrote your equations somewhere, presumably in the "Editor" window. When hovering over that, press "save" and it will save it as .m file

Comment: you can try saving your work looking at the history window

Answer (score 0):

.m - script file which contains the code you have written.

.mat - data file which contains all the values calculated during your Matlab session.

Most of the time you will want to write code in the Matlab Editor and save this code as a .m file. .mat files just contain the data itself. .mat files are typically used when running your code takes a very long time, and it is quicker to load the .mat file to obtain data than to re-run your .m script.